# Python: Find difference of dictionary's key[value] with other values and return the id which has the minimum difference

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I have been struggling on how to get the key(id) of the dictionary that has the minimum difference with a specific value.
for example,

I have a dictionary like,

```
dummy_w = {'Time': 1006120000,'T_id' : ''}
```

and the following,

```
dummy_R001 = {'Filename':"home/abc/de.csv",'Time':1006090000,'t_id':'x'}   
dummy_R002 = {'Filename':"home/abc/df.csv",'Time':1006100000,'t_id':'y'}  
dummy_R003 = {'Filename':"home/abc/d.csv",'Time':1026030000,'t_id':'z'}  
dummy_R004 = {'Filename':"home/abc/ef.csv",'Time':1026080000,'t_id':'p'}  
dummy_R005 = {'Filename':"home/abc/f.csv",'Time':1026120000,'t_id':'q'}
```

I want to assign the T_id for this dummy_w based on the difference with values of Time of each of the five dictionary's (dummy_R001 to _R005) Time.

I want to assign the one that has the minimum abs(time difference).

In this case the id assigned to dummy_w[T_id] should be 'y'.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: With `dummy_R001` etc being variables instead of list elements, I don't even want to attempt this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a one-liner where you iterate over all the `'Time'` values, calculate the `abs()` difference, and take the `min()` difference. Then assign it to `dummy_w['T_id']`:

```
min_diff = min((abs(dummy_w['Time']-d['Time']),d['t_id']) for d in [dummy_R001,dummy_R002,dummy_R003,dummy_R004,dummy_R005])
# (20000, 'y')

dummy_w['T_id'] = min_diff[1]
# {'T_id': 'y', 'Time': 1006120000}
```

Note, I'm not sure where `dummy_R001` etc. came from, but consider that you might have been better of starting with a nested dictionary where these were the keys instead of variable names.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Wow!!! You are a genius!! BTW, this is a meta data record for files under a specific folder which need to be matched with the output (file's record) of another measurement. I'll try nested dictionary! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `key` keyword argument to the `min` function:

```
>>> result = min(list_of_all_dicts, key=lambda d: abs(d['Time'] - dummy_w['Time']))
>>> result['t_id']
'y'
```